# Changing Date of Post Request

Tags: http-headers, web

Is there a way to alter the date a post to a form is made (through a header value, presumably), thereby changing its chronological order (in the case of a forum or other kind of thread-related platform)?  I can imagine most servers don't rely on the date provided by an incoming connection but I'm curious if there's any way.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're right—most server-side software doesn't rely on the date provided by the client, so there's typically no way to edit the server's conception of the date.